# Pandas: How do I merge the values of two dataframe columns that match within some tolerance?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to match two sets of rows in `pandas` dataframes containing positive and negative data, to within some user-defined `tolerance`, e.g. (initially):

```
timestamp value has_a_matching_minus should_match_tolerance_equals_ten
01  36.00    False False
02  68.00    False False
03  131.00   False False
04  94.00    False True
05  -1000.00 False False
06  100.00   False True
07  540.00   False False
08  -100.00  False False
09  54.00    False False
```

(create with:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': range(9), 'value': [36, 68, 131, 94, -1000, 100, 540, -100, 54]})
```

The `plusses` may or may not have one (or more) match in `minuses`. If a plus does mave a match within the tolerance, the corresponding row of `plusses` must have its column `'has_a_matching_minus'` set to `True` (otherwise it remains `False`).

I know I can make use of `df.between(low,high)`, but it only takes `low` and `high` as scalars and not series/dataframe columns.

How can I avoid the following (slow!) `for` loop over `between`? Should I rather be using `merge` etc.?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

minuses=data[data['value']<0.0]
plusses=data[data['value']>0.0]

tolerance = 10.0
match_queries      = np.abs(minusses)
match_queries_high = match_queries + tolerance
match_queries_low  = match_queries - tolerance

plusses['has_a_matching_minus'] = False
for (l, h) in zip(match_queries_low, match_queries_high):
    in_range = plusses['value'].between(l,h).astype(np.bool)
    plusses['has_a_matching_minus'] = plusses['has_a_matching_minus'] | in_range

assert(plusses['has_a_matching_minus']==plusses['should_match_tolerance_equals_ten'].all()), 'The acid test'
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples with expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks - done - but for some reason this question is tanking :(

Comment: Downvoters: Please rather provide constructive feedback :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the details of the question 100%, but the following can probably show how to approach it.

Suppose you start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': range(9), 'value': [36, 68, 131, 94, -1000, 100, 540, -100, 54]})
```

Use a dummy column to perform a self outer join:

```
df['dummy'] = 1
merged = pd.merge(df, df, on='dummy', how='outer')
```

Now calculate, per timestamp, whether there's a different negative value at most different from it in the absolute value at most 10 away:

```
merged['has_a_matching_minus'] = (merged.timestamp_x != merged.timestamp_y) & (merged.value_y < 0) & ((merged.value_x.abs() - merged.value_y.abs()).abs() < 10)

>>> merged.has_a_matching_minus.astype(int).groupby(merged.timestamp_x).max().astype(bool).to_frame()


has_a_matching_minus
timestamp_x 
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   True
4   False
5   True
6   False
7   False
8   False
```

You can easily `merge` this into the original frame. If you need several columns, perform their calculations on `merged` similarly.

Comment: I will add your test-data-creation line to the OP if that's OK.

Comment: I have actually come a cropper on this one - is there any chance we could discuss it in chat?

Comment: Except I can't find the chat button

Comment: @jtlz2 Hey, am unsure what you meant in your comment ("come a cropper"?). Could you perhaps edit your question or start a new one? I don't know why this one was so badly downvoted, BTW.

Comment: Many thanks on all counts - possibly because my initial version was so bad :\ It's annoying though that one can't tell whether it's lack of clarity vs usefulness. I will expand tomorrow, Tues, if that's ok. Thanks!

Comment: (come a cropper = come unstuck = messed up = gotten confused = fallen by the wayside? :) )

Comment: Hi Ami - so the issue is reassigning `merged` back onto the original frame `df` - is there any chance you could spell this step out in your answer? At the moment my `merged` and `df` have different lengths :\

Comment: @jtlz2 Are you sure that the result of `merged.has_a_matching_minus.astype(int).groupby(merged.timestamp_x).max().astype(bool).to_frame()
` has different length? In any case the idea is to use `pd.merge()` on the original and result, not concatenate - the order is not guaranteed to be the same.